# 4-20 mA loop powered ADC with display

Tags: power, adc, display, 4-20ma

I was asked to design a display that is loop powered and sits between the receiver and the transducer. I was wondering what's the best way to source power from the loop to power my electronics without damaging the receiver and the transducer? There are plenty of those products from manufacturers but is difficult to find a design. Thanks.

Comment: Wait, that 4-20 mA loop is a measurement loop, right? Can you link to one of these plenty products?

Comment: Yes that's a measurement loop, precisely a PLC connected to a Water Pressure Sensor.

Comment: good, but really: powering devices that are not measurement devices from a current measurement loop sounds like a bad idea, so that's why I'd really like to learn about these products that you mention. Can you please link to one or at least describe a product that is powered from a current measurement loop and not a sensor?

Comment: https://www.endress.com/en/Field-instruments-overview/System-Components-Recorder-Data-Manager/loop-powered-indicator-RIA15

Comment: Ah! Interesting! Really interesting. I now, too, wonder how they extract a (varying) power from a constant current loop without introducing a significant amount of noise.

Comment: @MarcusMüller actually it seems fairly simple as no matter how much voltage you drop (within limits), the transmitter will always ensure the correct current is drawn. Much like you might draw current from a voltage signal. However you do have to be aware not very much power is available.

Comment: @immibis well, considering digital circuits like the one used to drive the LCD panels in these products very likely want to have a stabilized supply voltage, there's bound to be some capacitive element parallel to the (changing) load. And that will lead to current variations on the supply side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a loop-powered 4/20 mA device, 4 mA is the absolute maximum current your device should need to operate correctly (ideally 2 mA max). That’s your first hurdle. Based on this, it sounds to me like the display should be low power tech like an LCD. There used to be plenty of dual slope integrating ADC chips that directly drive an LCD so that’s where I’d look first. Choose one that only needs a low voltage supply like 5 volts or less. They've been around for decades so I'm not sure how available they still are but they'll give you the simplest implementation I reckon.

The easiest (and most appropriate for current loops) line voltage regulation circuit is a zener diode that drops the 5 volts needed to power the circuit. That zener diode is going to waste a little current so you need to find one that doesn’t steal too much of the 4 mA needed to power the chip and LCD. Maybe choose a precision shunt zener because most of them will only waste sub 100 uA. If your circuit doesn't use the rest of the 4 mA, the zener will act as a shunt regulator and this keeps the "loop" noise-free but, just in case, put a 1 uF capacitor across it.

You also need to have a small series resistor so you can measure a voltage proportional to the current flow (the signal). Likely this will require a diff amp between resistor and ADC chip.

You need to establish how much volt drop the system can allow of course. If 5 volts isn’t a problem then use a zener. If, say 8 volts isn’t a problem then you can use a bridge rectifier as well as a zener so that your device will work on both connection polarities. There is still a lot of detail required but I hope this provides some small insight.

You could cheat a bit to get more current by using one of these: -

[image]

Note that it needs at least 10 volts across the loop terminals to guarantee working correctly. LT also have this idea: -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in a current loop, you actually will not loose current but rather you will decrease the voltage seen by the transmitter.

The voltage drop is proportional to the power you will be able to extract to power your LCD. The maximum voltage drop is given by the diode(s) you select but the second trade-off is that if you take too much current when bypassing the diode the voltage will collapse you will also not be able to extract any power from the diode (similar curve to the mpp of solar panels: 0W at short-circuit and 0W at open circuit and maximum power in between).

For a complete detail of how to get this setup running you can have a look at this reference design: [TIDA-00649](http://www.ti.com/tool/TIDA-00649#1)